# PyQt4 window size changes on different computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Problem:
The problem is best explained by looking at the two attached pictures of the same program. The picture of the smaller window was taken on a Notebook(Win 10)

[image: Notebook picture]

while the picture of the larger window was taken on a desktop PC(Win 10)

[image: desktop PC picture]

As you can see, the window enlarges on the desktop PC, which doesn't look good. It also happenes to other programs of mine: the text label sizes stay the same, the button sizes stay the same, but pictures get bigger and get blurry.

It doesn't matter if I use a layout manager like vertical or horizontal boxes or a grid layout or if I use fixed positioning. 
It just looks ugly.

Question:
I would like the window (and widgets) to keep its dimensions, as seen in the Notebook version.
Is there any way to achieve this? There has to be right?

Comment: Does one of the computers have a [high dpi display](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)?

Comment: The Notebook has these specifications: Screen: 12.3” PixelSense Display | Resolution: 2736 x 1824 (267 PPI) | Aspect ratio: 3:2 .

Comment: Sincer you do have a high dpi/ppi display, you will have to switch to pyqt5 if you want to resolve this issue (see the link in my previous comment).